# How to find the source code for boost.org libraries?

Tags: boost, open-source

The Boost Software License shows that software under this license is open-source. However, I can only find .hpp headers on boost.org's site and downloaded libraries. How to find the source code of the implementations of boost.org's libraries?

Comment: Do you know what templates are?

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès What do you mean by"what templates"? I'm interested in the implementation of some intrusive containers by boost.

Comment: Most of boost are templates, that means that the code is in the header. If you need some of boost lib code, it is easy to find.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès I see. I have found the source code for boost.intrusive containers right in the hpp files. Thanks so much. Could you further explain why are implementations contained in the headers for templates? Thank you!

Comment: Template are not code *per-se* but "templates of code", they are instanciated when you use it in code, so you need to get them available each time you use them. So as not being code but more of declaration, and need to be available in each portion of code, placing them in headers (at least include them) is the usual way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the boost libraries that aren't *header-only*, their source code can be found in the `libs` directory.
E.g. for `boost::filesystem`:

```
.../boost_1_63_0/libs/filesystem/src
```

Note: the `libs` directory is quite useful for *all* boost libraries, not just the non header-only libraries, since it usually contains library specific example and test code.